# How to wait for resolve dependencies before rendering a template in angular ui router state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to use the resolved data (using resolve block) in templateUrl function. How can I achieve that? Or can we wait for resolution to be comnplete before calling templateUrl function?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. [Why would you need that](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Comment: Our pages changes according to one response parameter, which is different per url & configured by admins.

Comment: Say, for example: a different home page template is rendered for a url a.xyz.com & a different for b.xyz.com being in a single state named as home state.

Comment: Well you have access to [`$stateParams`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates). But if you're dealing with different urls, why not just use different states? Or nested views?

Comment: Yes, thats not helpful. $stateParams only returns parameters matched in the state url. But we are adding a new configurable variable using $stateChangeStart to the $stateParams which is being used in rendering the template.

Comment: I think for what you're trying to do, your question does not contain enough information to be answered. Maybe add a simple [plunker](http://plnkr.co). // Have you checked the `templateProvider` config?

Comment: Okay, I'll modify my question description with some example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is auth service that need to check the user is authenticated or not before load the each view.

---

```
app.factory('appAuth', function ($http, $q, $location, $cookies, redirectToUrlAfterLogin, myHomePage) {
            var self = {};
            self.loginStatus= false;
            self.userDetails = {};
            self.Terminal = {};
            self.monument = {};
            self.loggedIn = function (callback) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http({
                        method: "GET",
                        url: 'rest/operator/loginStatus'
                    }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                        if (callback) 
                            callback(response.IsSuccess, response.data);  
                        deferred.resolve();
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                };
            self.loggedOut = function(callback){
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: 'rest/operator/logout'
                    }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                        if (callback) 
                            callback(response.IsSuccess, response.data);  
                        deferred.resolve();
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                };        
            self.saveAttemptUrl = function () {
                if ($location.path().toLowerCase() != '/login') {
                    redirectToUrlAfterLogin.url = $location.path();
                } else {
                    redirectToUrlAfterLogin.url = myHomePage.url;
                }
            };
            self.redirectToAttemptedUrl = function () {
                    $location.path(redirectToUrlAfterLogin.url);
                };
            return self;
        });



-- config Section of Angular use this.

 $routeProvider
            .when("/", angularAMD.route({
               templateUrl: function (rp) { return rootUrl + 'index.html'; },
               controllerUrl: rootUrl + "indexController.js",
               resolve: {
                   login: function($q,appAuth,$rootScope) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    appAuth.loggedIn(function(err, data){
                        appAuth.loginStatus = true;
                        $rootScope.ConfigVersion = data.monument.ConfigVersion;
                        $rootScope.monument = data.monument;
                        if (!err) {
                            appAuth.loginStatus = false;
                            appAuth.userDetails = {};
                            appAuth.Terminal = {};
                            appAuth.mounument = {};
                            deferred.resolve();
                            return;
                        }   
                        if (data.User == 0) {
                            appAuth.loginStatus = false;
                            deferred.resolve();
                            return;
                        }
                        appAuth.userDetails = data.userDetails;
                        appAuth.Terminal = data.model;
                        appAuth.monument = data.monument;
                        deferred.resolve();
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                   }
               }
            }))
```

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve it while setting up the angular routing -

Sample :

```
$routeProvider.when("/home", {
    controller: "HomeController", templateUrl: "/app/home/home.html",
    resolve: {
        user: function (SessionService) {
            return SessionService.getCurrentUser();
        }
    }
});
```

With  resolve, you  are setting up the dependcies to your controller . If these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and set as a value before the controller is loaded and before the $routeChangeSuccess event is fired.

resolve is a key, value pair -

- key :  string name of a dependency that will be injected into the controller
- value : factory, where the factory can either be a string of the name of a service, a function whose result is injected into the controller, or a promise that is to be resolved

Comment: Okay. But what is difference in defining a state & using a `$routeProvider.when()` function?

Comment: Looks like, 2nd argument in when (handler) does not accept an object. It only accepts a function & string. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#when-for-redirection

Comment: well, you no where mentioned about using ui-router. so I gave the example of angular routing.

Comment: Oh, okay. Well I had added the tag for angular ui router. It doesn't helped.

Comment: What if templateUrl is a function and I need to use a promise right there? templateUrl is called before resolving for some reason.